# Bash - SSH to remote server and retrieve data

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a bash script that needs to connect to another server for parts of it's execution. I have tried many of the standard instructions and syntaxes for executing ssh commands, but with little progress.

On the remote server, I need to source a shell script that contains several env parameters for some software. One of these parameters are then used in a filepath to point to an executable, which contains a function ' -lprojects ' that can list the projects for the software on that server.

I have verified that running the commands on the server itself works multiple times. My issue is when I try to run the same commands over SSH. If I use the approach where I use the env variable for the filepath, it shows that the variable is null in the filepath, giving a file/directory not found error. If I hard-code the filepath to point to the executable, it gives me an error saying that the shell script is not sourced (which I assume it needs for other functions and apis for the executable to reveal it's -lprojects function)

Here is how the code looks like somewhat:

```
ssh remote.server 'source /filepath/remotescript.sh'
filelist=$(ssh remote.server $REMOTEVARIABLE'/bin/executable -lprojects')

echo ${filelist[@]}

for file in $filelist
do
    echo $file
    ssh SERVER2 awk 'something' /filepath/"$file"/somefile.txt | sed 'something' >> filepath/values.csv;

done
```

As you can see, I then also need to loop through the contents of the -lprojects output in the remote.server, do some awk and sed on the files to extract the wanted text (this works), but then I need to write that back to the client (local server) values.csv file. This is more generic, as there will be several servers I have to do this for, but all of them have to write to the same .csv file. For simplicity, you can just regard this as a one remote server case, since it is vital I get it working for at least one now in the beginning.

Note that I also tried something like:

```
ssh remote.server << EOF
    'source /filepath/remotescript.sh'
    filelist=$(ssh remote.server $REMOTEVARIABLE'/bin/executable -lprojects')
EOF
```

But with similar results. Also placing the single-quotes in the filelist both before and after the remotevariable, etc.

How do I go about properly doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access the environment variable, you must source the script that defines the environment within the same SSH call as the one where you are using it, otherwise, you're running your commands in two different shells which are unrelated:

```sh
filelist=$(ssh remote.server 'source /filepath/remotescript.sh; $REMOTEVARIABLE/bin/executable -lprojects')
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `executable` outputs one file name per line, you can use readarray to achieve the effect :

```
readarray -t filelist < <(ssh remote.server '
source /filepath/remotescript.sh
$REMOTEVARIABLE/bin/executable -lprojects
'
)

echo ${filelist[@]}

for file in $filelist
do
    echo $file
    ssh SERVER2 awk 'something' /filepath/"$file"/somefile.txt | sed 'something' >> filepath/values.csv;

done
```